# CSS using absolute positioning on scaled images results in further scaling of images

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

Thank you for your response.  I have images loaded into a container that is positioned relatively.  These images are scaled to 17% of its size.  I would like to use absolute positioning to change the position of these images on my screen (required).  However, when I do so, the images seem to rescale themselves again.  I am not certain what I am doing wrong, however I will say, that when I use relative positioning on different images which are also scaled I have no issue at all.  A lame work around is to use transform :scale to scale up the images after being moved, but I am not certain why I am having this issue at all. - Thank you !

```css
#div2{
        width: 700px;
        background-color: green; 

    }
  
    #div3{
        width: 900px;
        background-color: orange; 
        position: relative; 
    }
  
   #blob {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 17%;
        height: 17%; 
        object-fit: contain;
        position: absolute;
        right : 160px;
        bottom: 315px;  
    }
```

```html
<div id="div3">
  <div id="div2"> 
    <img id="blob" src="imgs/blobt.png" alt="blob"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your code does not work.**
You *should* be using **classes** to do styling most of the time.

If I set a **height** to parent elements and a **z-index** to the image it's working.

```css
.div2{
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: green; 
}

.div3{
  width: 900px;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: orange; 
  position: relative; 
}
  
.blob {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 17%;
  height: 17%; 
  object-fit: contain;
  position: absolute;
  right : 160px;
  bottom: 315px;  
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="div3">
  <div class="div2"> 
    <img class="blob" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619366501246-e8f14df10fcb?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="Mountain waterfall"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

*Let's add some extended explanation*

There are lots of useful articles about the difference of **ids and classes.**

My personal point of view, I try to reserve ids to do JavaScript manipulation, it's more performant to look for a unique key rather than a class, ids are also useful to do page navigation with a link. So, that's why I don't like using them for styling, and classes are useful to (don't)not repeat yourself (DRY), you can use it over and over again, so you may style a div using an id, and later you realize you need the exact same css for another piece of html, you can't add another id tag.

**% width and height are calculated based on first ancestor that has those attributes. Otherwise browsers can't do their maths.**

Comment: Thank you Felipe - it now works -thank you so much (the code was a snippet).  Can you explain why what you did made the difference ?  Why should I not use ID, but instead class.  How does setting the height on the parent affect scale ?  Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Yeah, sure, I'll add some explanation, If it was useful upvote the response. @Jax

Comment: Thank you Felipe, that makes sense to me (diff between id vs class).. so the scale issue was created by not defining the height on the div ?  (I cannot upvote you because lack of karma.. I'm so sorry, maybe someone else can? )

Comment: Yeah, exactly, the browser can't do their math and calculate it's size if it hasn't an ancestor with those attributes defined. @Jax

Comment: No problem @Jax